# Install Gimp at web server

Tags: webserver, gimp

I want to take an HTTP GET request on my server and then run GIMP script-fu based on the parameters sent by the request. So, I need to first install GIMP on my server right? Care to tell me how to install GIMP on a web server?

Comment: Btw, unless you are using a GImp plugin that has no non-Gimp equivalent, you can probably implement your image processing around ImageMagick or a Pythin script  around the pillow library.

Comment: Or, if you want to use the same operations GIMP is using (and using more and more currently), you could have a look at GEGL: http://www.gegl.org/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the server OS (and on the distro type, if Linux). It can be as simple as `apt install gimp` for a Debian-style distro (Debian, Ubuntu) or `yum install gimp` for the RedHat variants.